# Open an expanded item in a list with AngularDart component

Tags: dart, angular-components, angular-dart

It's been used `MaterialListComponent` and `MaterialListItemComponent` components to make lists in an Application with AngularDart.

When one *item* of type `MaterialListItemComponent` is selected, I would like a behaviour similar to first [ExpansionPanel](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#material_expansion_panel) example of the AngularDart Gallery. *Open the item expanded*. But with this component, I didn't found a way to put more information when it are closed, like image (avatar), more labels, buttons.

Here another example, with the *Google Inbox* mail:

***List items closed:***
[image]

***One Item of the list opened and expanded:***
[image]

This that I would like to implement.

Is there any way or suggestions to implement this with AngularDart Components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaterialExpansionPanel allows for a few ng-content areas to configure the header area.

The [name], [value], and [action] areas.

In this case it sounds like you want to use the action content area. It only shows when the content is closed. You can see this in the Edit/Duplicate example [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#material_expansion_panel). It hides the header, but you wouldn't need to.

Comment: Great! Using these area attributes it is actually possible to configure the header anyway, including images, multiple lines, and actions.